# Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Tool'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have item in array of:

```
export interface Tool {
    label: string;
    visible?: boolean;
    icon?: string;
    devider?: boolean;
    onClick: () => void;
}

this.controls = [
            {
                label: 'Перемещение',
                visible: true,
                icon: 'fas fa-arrows-alt fa-fw fa-lg mr-2',
                onClick: () => {
                    this.dispatch(this.activateMoveAction.bind(this), this);
                },
            }];
```

And dispather:

```
dispatch(dispatcher: Function, control: Tool) {}
```

Why do I get this error on the line: `.bind(this),` **this**);

```
Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Tool'.
```

This solves my issue but look awful:

```
   this.dispatch(this.activateMoveAction.bind(this), this.controls[0]);
```

Comment: your dispatch function expects 2 parameters: (1 function and one object with type Tool).
The first argument is ok, the second needs to be an object with type tool, but you are passing the keyword `this` instead.

Comment: I want to pass element in array inside `this.dispatch()` as the second parameter

Comment: I got the problem, but why the second parameters `this` no reffers to element of array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happening because you use arrow function that preserves context (this). If you will use regular function, it will have correct context.

You can read more about arrow functions here: https://2ality.com/2012/04/arrow-functions.html